# Search An Enum Value inside of An Enum

Tags: vb.net, enums

I've tried the code below but it always returns nothing, It should enter

```
Protected Function GetTotalDebitAmount(ByRef roEntryDetailRecordBaseList As List(Of PPDEntryDetailRecord)) As String
    Dim iTotal As Integer = 0
    If Me.BatchHeaderRecord.ServiceClassCode = Convert.ToString(CInt(ServiceClassCodes.EntriesMixedDebitsAndCredits)) Then
        For Each oEntryDetailRecord As PPDEntryDetailRecord In roEntryDetailRecordBaseList
            If CBool(Array.IndexOf([Enum].GetValues(GetType(TransactionCodes.Debits)), CInt(oEntryDetailRecord.TransactionCode)) > 0) Then
                iTotal += CInt(oEntryDetailRecord.Amount)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return CStr(iTotal)
End Function
```

I need some one who evaluate the part below:

```
If CBool(Array.IndexOf([Enum].GetValues(GetType(TransactionCodes.Debits)), CInt(oEntryDetailRecord.TransactionCode)) > 0) Then
```

Thanks.

Comment: All I had to do was `Enum.IsDefined()` method:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways,

I've found the answer:

```
If [Enum].IsDefined(GetType(TransactionCodes.Debits), CInt(oEntryDetailRecord.TransactionCode)) Then
                    iTotal += CInt(oEntryDetailRecord.Amount)
End If
```